# Помогите с запросом SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Есть `TextBox` в который вводятся буквы и по этим буквам база выдает мне результат поиска. Вот код:

```
private void tbSearchPC_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath("Database.mdf");
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + fullPath + ";Integrated Security=True";

    myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myConnection.Open();

    if(Menu1_1On == 1)
        query = "SELECT * FROM Computers WHERE (Name) LIKE (N'%" + tbSearchPC.Text + "%')";

    if (Menu1_2On == 1)
        query = "SELECT * FROM Laptops WHERE (Name) LIKE (N'%" + tbSearchPC.Text + "%')";

    if (Menu1_3On == 1)
        query = "SELECT * FROM Smartphones WHERE (Name) LIKE (N'%" + tbSearchPC.Text + "%')";

    if (Menu1_4On == 1)
        query = "SELECT * FROM Tablets WHERE (Name) LIKE (N'%" + tbSearchPC.Text + "%')";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    GetData(reader);

}
```

Также есть кнопка сортировки по возрастанию и по убыванию. Вот код:

```
private void SortUpToDown(string sender)
{
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath("Database.mdf");
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + fullPath + ";Integrated Security=True";

    myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myConnection.Open();
    if (sender == "Name")
    {
        if (Menu1_1On == 1)
            //query = "SELECT * FROM Computers ORDER BY Name ASC and WHERE (Name) LIKE (N'%" + tbSearchPC.Text + "%'"; //<- пытался сделать что-то вроде этого
            query = "SELECT * FROM Computers ORDER BY Name ASC";
        if (Menu1_2On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Laptops ORDER BY Name ASC";

        if (Menu1_3On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Smartphones ORDER BY Name ASC";

        if (Menu1_4On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Tablets ORDER BY Name ASC";
    }
    if (sender == "Price")
    {
        if (Menu1_1On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Computers ORDER BY Price ASC";

        if (Menu1_2On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Laptops ORDER BY Price ASC";

        if (Menu1_3On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Smartphones ORDER BY Price ASC";

        if (Menu1_4On == 1)
            query = "SELECT * FROM Tablets ORDER BY Price ASC";
    }
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    GetData(reader);
    myConnection.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Как составить правильно запрос, чтобы я мог выводить в отсортированном виде не только ВСЕ записи в таблице по заданному столбцу и методу сортировки, но и сортировать записи, которые мне выдала база ПОСЛЕ ПОИСКА?

Сейчас работает так: загружается форма и выполняется запрос к базе на показ ВСЕХ записей таблицы. Далее я ввожу в текстовое поля буквы для поиска - база выдает результат, а вот когда я нажимаю кнопку сортировки мне база выдает ВСЕ записи в таблице. Мне же нужно вывести только записи после поиска в отсортированном виде.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте свой код в виде текста, а не картинок. Нажмите на пункт `править`, чуть ниже тегов вопроса, уберите картинки, отступите вниз две строки от обычн.текста и вправо на 4 знака и сделайте вставку из буфера своего кода.

Comment: Исправлено @Bulson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кэшируйте ваш найденный пул записей. Используя `List<T>` либо другую перечислимую коллекцию. Кэш будет обновляться каждый раз, когда Вы будете делать запрос к БД. Когда нужно отсортировать, то используйте уже не БД, а ваш кэш. Пример работы сортировки в случае `List<T>` и LINQ:

```
List<MyDBEntry> list;// кэш
list=GetDataByFilter(); //запись в кэш данных из БД по фильтру
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x=>x.Price).ToList(); // сортировка с использованием ранее созданного кэша
```

**UPD**:

Чтобы избежать создания перегруженного класса-обертки `MyDBEntry`, можно работать с типом `dynamic`.
Если стоит цель сортировать только по одному полю, и вы уверены, что оно есть во всех записях БД, то для сортировки можно использовать следующий метод, подавая на вход `List<dynamic>`. При этом кэш будет выглядеть как `List<dynamic>`. Предварительно ваши записи из БД нужно скастовать к `dynamic`:

```
MyList = GetDataByFilter().Cast<dynamic>().ToList();

public List<dynamic> Sort(List<dynamic> input, string property)
{   
    return input.OrderBy(p => p.GetType()
                               .GetProperty(property)
                               .GetValue(p, null)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Только какого типа должны быть элементы в коллекции? Судя по коду автора они могут быть разные и, скорее всего, они не имеют общего потомка (кроме object)